# how to get width and height from a svg div by js

Tags: javascript, html, svg

There is a div in html as follow:

```
<svg id="box" width="312" height="101"></svg>
```

I want to get the svg tag's width and height:

```
var el = window.document.querySelector('#box');
```

But I cant get the width and height by `el`, How do I get them? 
I use node.js to run the script. And the whole code is:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom'),
content = '<svg id="box" width="300" height="120"></svg>';

jsdom.env({ features : { QuerySelector : true }, html : content,
      done : function(errors, window) {
      var w =  window.document.querySelector('#box').attr("width");
      console.log(w);
     }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you try with [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) ?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, it can not do.

Comment: @dingo_d this code has beed used in jsdom.env()...

Comment: @RobertLongson TypeError: undefined is not a function... the error prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myelm = document.getElementById("box").getAttribute('width');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) which is [well-supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=getBoundingClientRec):

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an
>   element and its position relative to the viewport.

```
var node = document.getElementById("yourElement");
var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log("width:" + rect.width );
console.log("height:" + rect.height);
```

Comment: In case it matters, note that *In IE8 and below, the DOMRect object returned by getBoundingClientRect() lacks height and width properties*.